# SQL query on a random row via Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using ORACLE database and I am trying to access one random row from my SQL query however the query is not retrieving back a random row and I am not sure what I did wrong?

My query is:

```
SELECT a.car_id, b.product_id
FROM listing a, carProduct b
WHERE a.car_id = b.car_id
AND a.certified = 'TRUE'
AND b.product_id like '%CERT'
AND rownum = 1
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
```

Comment: what do you mean by *not working correctly*?

Comment: @vkp I have edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rownum` has to come *after* the `order by`.  You need a subquery:

```
SELECT lcp.*
FROM (SELECT l.car_id, cp.product_id
      FROM listing l join
           carProduct cp
           on l.car_id = cp.car_id
      WHERE l.certified = 'TRUE' AND cp.product_id like '%CERT'
      ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
     ) lcp
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Use table aliases that make sense, such as abbreviations for the table names.
- The `rownum = 1` needs to go in the outer query.
- In Oracle 12c+, you don't need a subquery.  You can just use `fetch first 1 row only`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is very helpful! One question, what does `lcp.*` do? I tried googling it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Robben . . . It selects all the columns from the subquery in the `from` clause that is labelled `lcp`.